# installing ubuntu 13.10 in vaio

Tags: installation, dual-boot, vaio

everything works properly when i am booting from usb (trial mode). but when i am trying to install, it shows that it didnot find any operating system but i do have windows 8 preinstalled. when i did click something else, i am also able to see my diskpartitions and an install click option.i am fearing that something will happen to windows 8 when i install ubuntu 13.10. there is a chance that i may not access windows 8 after installing ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got this done by proceeding with "something else".. followed by boot-repair

i created the following partitions and installed ubuntu on my pc.

1 --> ext4 \     for  about 15gb
2 --> ext4 \boot for  about 200mb
and
3 --> swap area  for  about 4gb(depends on the RAM ,mine is 4gb)

i noticed that windows starts automatically before doing boot-repair,so proceed with boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair as soon as you install ubuntu.

if this is not done before you restart your pc then boot the ubuntu image file again and do boot-repair after entering into "try ubuntu before installing"